# Current recommended method of including AWS Embedded C SDKs in an ESP-IDF project?

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, esp32, aws-iot, esp-idf

What is the most up to date method of including the AWS Embedded C SDKs in an ESP-IDF project? [This repo](https://github.com/espressif/esp-aws-iot) has examples and a submodule with the source files, but upon checking the examples, I see that they have not been updated in 2 years and use the deprecated wifi event loop system. Is this still the recommened repo to use or is it deprecated?

Furthermore, the [submodule](https://github.com/espressif/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/tree/61f25f34712b1513bf1cb94771620e9b2b001970) that contains the actual source files is also embedded in this repo. Is it recommended to only clone this submodule instead of the entire `esp-aws-iot` repo?

What I have been doing so far is cloning the `esp-aws-iot` repo into the `components` folder of whatever project I am working on and just replacing the deprecated portions of the examples with their up to date counterparts.

Is this still the proper way of doing things or is there a more current method of implementing these SDKs into IDF projects?